# Multiple lookup to the same table in laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I'm a beginner learning laravel and ran into a strange problem.  I would like one table to reference the same lookup table twice.  For example, if I had a messages table which stores messages between two users.

If my messages table structure is like:

- id - unsigned (auto incrementing pk)
- message - string
- user1_id - unsigned
- user2_id - unsigned

How should I set up the messages and users models so when displaying an index of the messages, it shows the user.email for user1 and user2 from the users table?

If there was just 1 user per message, I could name the column 'user_id' and then have a belongsTo relationship to the users table.

It seems like it might involve using the $appends property, but how should things be configured to retrieve the 2 users' email addresses when querying the messages table and send those along with the the message data to the view?

Answer (score 0):

Someone helped me on the laracasts forum and I figured I'd post the answer here in case it's helpful.

The answer is to set up additional relationships in the message model.  Like:

public function userOne() {

```
  return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'user1');
```

}

public function userTwo() {

```
  return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'user2');
```

}

Then in the view, assuming you passed the messages as $messages, in the foreach $messages as $message loop, use the optional() helper to get the data like this:

{{ optional( $message->userOne)->email }}

Answer (score 0):

```
public function userOne() {

  return $this->hasOne(User::class, 'id', 'user1_id');
}
```

```
public function userTwo() {

  return $this->hasOne(User::class, 'id', 'user2_id');
}
```

Comment: The Eloquent ORM contains a method called `belongsTo` which could be used. Another approach could be by using the `Searchable trait` by extending your User Model. See below link:

https://echebaby.com/blog/2021-02-13-searchable-trait-to-search-in-multiple-columns-with-laravel/